# AutoCompleteTextView items is not clickable / selectable

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Suppose I have the following `AutoCompleteTextView`:

```
final AutoCompleteTextView actvCategory = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvCategory);
actvCategory.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.category_list_item_layout, R.id.category_list_item_title, items));
actvCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        actvCategory.setText(items.get(i));
    }
});
```

With the following item layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_list_item_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:background="@drawable/np_blue"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/category_list_item_delete_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/delete_item"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/np_light_blue"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When user starts to type in text field it is okay, and right suggestions will be shown, But these suggestions is not clickable(= when user click on it no thing happens). As I know the problem is about the `ImageButton` in the layout file, when I remove it every things is okay as expected but when it exists this problem raised. I also have tried `focusable=false` for it but no luck.

Can anyone please help me out where is problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your *ImageButton* is un-clickable, you probably want to use *ImageView*.

It works mostly the same as the `ImageButton`, but it isn't clickable.

Comment: But I want to attach a click listener to it!

Comment: You want to attach an onItemClick listener, right? If I understood correctly, you want the whole layout to be clickable, but currently the ImageButton is causing problems. Replace the ImageButton with an ImageView, and the whole layout(Image + text) will be clickable and trigger the onItemClick event.

Comment: Many thanks to your response, But I want to implement different logic for `ImageButton` click listener and `onItemClickListener`